# How to use ng-bind-html with two-way databinding?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, contenteditable

I'm currently working on a simple editor built with angular. The main textbox is just a div with the contenteditable set to true and the ng-bind-html attribute, like this:

```
<div contenteditable="true" ng-bind-html="field.content">HTML content here</div>
```

The value is set and rendered properly with the right tags and look at page load. But since it's only bound one way I my data or model isn't updated upon edit.

I've tried some contenteditable directivs but most of them requires ng-model, but if I add that my html tags are not rendered and converted into symbols.

### How would I go about updating my data after the div's content have been changed and also keep the HTML tags and so on formatted correctly?

EDIT: Just using this temporary "fix" for the time being, but I would like something more robust.

```
<div contenteditable="true" ng-bind-html="field.content" 
ng-blur="saveHTML($event)"></div>

$scope.saveHTML = function(event) {
    this.field.content = event.target.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Look at sample in the $compile documentation http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile

Comment: What version of Angular? I recently looked at Contenteditable fields and ng-bind (it might have been ng-model) and as far as I could tell they are adding behavior for this in 1.2. Not sure about the html part though.

Comment: @ErikHonn I'm using version 1.2.0-rc.2. Yeah I tried ng-model but without luck, it just ignores or converts my HTML tags. But it could be me doing it wrong.

Comment: Never actually tried using it (I couldn't switch to the rc on the project I was working on), so can't help you there I'm afraid. If need be it is probably not that hard to make your own directive. Accept a variable name like bind and model does and assign to that whenever the inner html changes.

Comment: @ErikHonn Okay well thanks anyway! I'll definitely dig into Directives  later when I have time, for now I'm using this semi-dirty fix that I edited into my post above.

Comment: Any update on this? I've run into the same problem. I have to use $sce.trustAsHtml and ng-bind-html to get HTML stored into my database to display... but this breaks two-way binding. If a user edit's the HTML then it will save to the database (if I invoke $sce.trustAsHTML again) but the view will not update.

Comment: Haven't had the time revisit the code yet I'm afraid. I'm planning to switch over to using [**Sir Trevor**](http://madebymany.github.io/sir-trevor-js/) which seems to just be a more robust version of what I currently have built. Maybe you could look at their code to see how they manage their data? It's built on just regular javascript.